# Form validators not passing in Angular 2

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm creating a form in Angular 2 using some form validators via the form builder.

Whenever I enter data in the text box - it passes(color of div outline goes green).

When I load the form with data, the textboxes have a red outline - even though they're populated with text.

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!firstname.valid), 'has-success': (firstname.valid)}">
        <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input [formControl]="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="{{profile.firstname}}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In component file:

```
@Input() profile: Profile;

public form: FormGroup;
public firstname: AbstractControl;
public lastname: AbstractControl;


    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
        'firstname': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
        'lastname': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
        'jobtitle': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
        'department': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])]
    });

    this.firstname = this.form.controls['firstname'];
    this.lastname = this.form.controls['lastname'];
    this.jobtitle = this.form.controls['jobtitle'];
    this.department = this.form.controls['department'];
}
```

Why is the validation not passing, is `Validators.required` not correct?

Thanks.

Comment: your code seems fine, could you recreate your problem on pulnker ?

Comment: will take me a while to get that. Seems the  "has-error" class is set to early. class="form-group row has-error"

Comment: so that mean you get your solution ?

Comment: No unfortunatley not:)  The controls in the component are set as Abstract Controls.  ..is that right?

Comment: may be not sure :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using model-driven forms, why not setting the initial value using the model-driven way:

```
'firstname': [profile.firstname, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])]
```

If you don't have the data at hand during init phase and really need to update it later at some time, use:

```
this.firstname.updateValue(this.profile.firstname);
```

Working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UgsYOu04H0Y4kxGYwhAl?p=preview